# Set MediaPlayer's timeout?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, google-tv

Is there a way to set the timeout value of the MediaPlayer to so it doesn't cause an error so soon if the video doesn't play?

The problem is that my videos are on a CDN. If the video hasn't been cached on the CDN yet, then it may take a little bit to load the video while the 1st person access the video. On other platforms (i.e. HTML5's video tag) this is not a problem - the video plays just fine.

My theory is that the MediaPlayer times out from attempting to play the video.

If this is true, then is it possible I can change when the time out happens? If I cannot set this value, is there another proven method that might work?

p.s. My app is built for the Google TV platform.

Comment: Not quite what you want, but you might force the app to try to access the stream twice, i.e. you can retry the connection after a timeout when catching exception (or in `onErrorListener`).

Comment: Please detail your hardware device, manufacturer, model, release.

In the logcat, do you see something like "CURL Transfer finished with error"?

Comment: The error code seems to be "100". The device is a 2013 Sony googleTV device. I would attempt to load the video a 2nd time; however, it takes a long time (10-20) before the error occurs, so it's not a great user experience for the user to wait up to 40 seconds to potentially see an error message.   The weird thing is that an HTML video player doesn't have this problem playing the same videos, but the Android Video pLayer does. Thanks!